# How to avoid iOS browser privacy prompt when navigating to an OAuth login page

Tags: ios, react-native, oauth-2.0

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472927/b2c-popup-on-ios-my-app-wants-to-use-b2clogin-com-to-sign-in) but for React Native. We are using [react-native-app-auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth) to handle OAuth login with Azure B2C using the Authorization Code flow.

When the user opens the login screen on iOS they are prompted with a browser security message saying "'Example' wants to use 'b2clogin.com' to sign in". This interruption is far from an ideal user flow, but we want to follow security best practices and use OAuth for our authentication.

Based on the number of articles I've seen about this I believe it's possible to avoid this warning by setting [prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession/3237231-prefersephemeralwebbrowsersessio) to `true` on `ASWebAuthenticationSession` however we haven't been able to find a working example of how to do this with React Native.

Some articles suggesting this is possible:

- https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/issues/723 (people have suggested they've managed to implement their own `OIDExternalUserAgentIOS` but there are no examples I could find of how to do this with React Native)
- https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/issues/66
- https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/177
- https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/402
- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2/issues/114 (it's possible in MSAL for Xarmarin.iOS)

Comment: That component seems to rely on the [openId](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-iOS/) package which uses `SFSafariViewController` rather than `ASWebAuthenticationSession` - You might need to look for a different library

Comment: It looks like there's a release for [AppAuth-iOS 1.60](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/milestone/5) which includes [these changes](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/pull/645) to support setting `prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession`.